# random color scheme using slide bar

Tags: android, layout, colors, switch-statement

I am attempting to make a slider bar that randomly changes the color of several parts of the users interface when the user slides the bar from one side to the other.  I have a piece of code that already works but I know it's not as efficient as it could be.  I have 3 of the same layout modifiers as below:

```
    private void getLayout2(){

    int color = 0;

    final Random randColor2 = new Random();
    int control = randColor2.nextInt(4);

    switch(control){

    case 0: color = getResources().getColor(R.color.White);
    Log.i(TAG, "color is white");
    break;

    case 1: color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Red);
    Log.i(TAG, "color is red");
    break;

    case 2: color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow);
    Log.i(TAG, "color is yellow");
    break;

    case 3: color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue);
    Log.i(TAG, "color is blue");
    break;

    }

    Layout2.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return;
}
```

What I would like to do is change all of the layout backgrounds in the same piece of code but I am not sure how to do that as there is only one color variable and I don't want all the colors to be the same at any given time.  Currently I am just calling multiple versions of this method for each layout in the "onProgressChanged" method of the slider listener.  Can this be done in a single method with this scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options. You can have your function return a the color and set it your main routine, or you can pass the layout as a parameter to your function.  An example of the latter follows. Since this is a function, the color variable is recreated every time it is called, so no need to worry that it will be the same when you call the function a different time.  Try it and see.

```
     private void setRandomBackgroundColor(View layout){

         int color = 0;

         final Random randColor = new Random();
         int control = randColor.nextInt(4);

         switch(control) {

         case 0: 
             color = getResources().getColor(R.color.White);
             Log.i(TAG, "color is white");
             break;

         case 1: 
             color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Red);
             Log.i(TAG, "color is red");
             break;

         case 2: 
             color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow);
             Log.i(TAG, "color is yellow");
             break;

         case 3: 
             color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue);
             Log.i(TAG, "color is blue");
             break;
         }

         layout.setBackgroundColor(color);

         return;
}
```